# Find the fundamental group of the torus with an open disc removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to find a fundamental group of $\mathbb{T} \setminus \mathbb{D}$, the $2$-torus $\mathbb{T}$ with an open disc $\mathbb{D}$ removed. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try to see the torus as $\frac{\mathbb{R}^2}{\mathbb{Z}^2}$

Comment: Or even easier, see the torus as a square modulo some relation on its boundary.

Comment: The question seems to be about the fundamental group of $\mathbb{T}^2 \setminus \mathbb{D}$, not the torus itself.

Comment: @Martin yes, you are right

Comment: I edited your question to remove possible ambiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Big hint: View the torus as the square $I^2/\sim$ with the usual equivalence relation $\sim$ identifying opposite edges, and then removes a small disk from the interior of $I^2$. Can you see how this space is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of some number of circles? (I'll leave you to figure out how many)

Comment: We will wide the hole so that there will be only one boundary. Then collapse two sides and obtain a wedge of two circles. Why they should not be collapsed too?

Comment: To put it precisely, you're performing a deformation retract on to the 1-skeleton, and the 1-skeleton is a wedge of two circles so you  can not deform the space any more (similar to if you punctured a disk and then deformation retracted that on to the boundary circle). Another method for calculating the fundamental group of this space would be to use Van-Kampen's Theorem where $U$ is an open annulus around the removed disk, and $V$ is the entire space with a slightly thinner annulus removed from around the removed disk.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So the answer is Z*Z?

Comment: Yes it is. Now try and work out the fundamental group of the klein bottle with a disk removed, and the real projective plane with a disk removed :).